# External TV tuner for my monitor?

Tags: display, tv

I'm living in the dorms at the moment. I have access to the standard TV cable.

The problem is that I have only HDMI, DVI, and VGA ports in my monitor(it's a monitor after all).

I was wondering if there are any other ways of connecting the TV cable to my monitor without the use of a PC. I mean that the cable goes from the wall to a device that converts the tv cable to either one of the inputs my monitor takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are external tuners that have HDMI outputs that you can connect to your monitor with (e.g. http://www.ambery.com/anvitodvcowi.html).

You will want a digital tuner though as that is what all US signals are now. Probably something similar to this: [KWorld SA295-Q DE](http://www.justechn.com/2009/12/07/review-kworld-external-atscqam-tvbox-hdmi-edition-sa295-q-de).

Comment: Although expensive, this looks really awesome. Would this work in the US?

Comment: Beats me, it was just meant for a proof of concept. They are located in California, so I would assume so though.

Comment: http://www.sabrent.com/category/tv-video-capture/TV-LCDHR/
apparently, you need a "converter box" for this to work in the states. Dang it!!

Comment: Ah, I see what you are asking now. They are analog tuners and all US broadcasts are digital now. Therefore you would have to get an analog to digital converter. These were the devices that the government [or whoever it was] was giving vouchers for so people could get them for free instead of having to buy one or buy a newer TV with a digital tuner.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally - ''The TV Tuner devices are providing you with the ability to use your computer as a normal, fully functional TV. There are TV Tuner cards, TV Tuner USB sticks, and stand-alone TV tuners available in almost every PC shop. The TV Tuner cards are usually PCI based, and are usually installed/used mainly in desktop PCs, while the compact USB TV Tuners are the best choice for your laptop. The stand-alone TV Tuners are capable of receiving analog and digital TV signals without the need of any extra software...'' You can read the full article @ http://ergohelper.asia/?p=73

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

A more hack-ish and probably cheaper solution than a dedicated analog tuner with HDMI output is to use

- a VCR (assuming you have one available or can get it cheap: this is a common case) that most likely will have an analog tuner and SCART/S-VHS output (depending on where in the world you are) and
- an active SCART→HDMI converter.

At least where I am this would cost less than half of what a dedicated tuner with HDMI output costs, once again: assuming you can get the VCR cheap.

I have an old VCR for a similar purpose rigged up, but the specific monitor in this case takes component input directly so I don't need an extra converter.

Comment: This would also require a analog to digital converter box placed before the VCR, correct?

Comment: @user142485: No, the VCR takes an analog signal. Where I currently live I get TV from both an analog RF signal and a digital (DVB-C) signal, both directly from a wall socket. The analog RF signal comes via a coaxial cable and is exactly the same type of signal as from an old antenna. This goes directly into the VCR, and then to my monitor. The monitor has an internal A/D converter to go from an analog component signal to its digital 720p panel. If the monitor had only had digital inputs, as in the questioner's case, I would have also needed the mentioned SCART->HDMI converter _after_ the VCR.

Comment: Ok, I guess I did not know there was much for analog channels left. In a dorm I would guess it's mainly digital.

Comment: @user142485: It depends on where you are in the world. My country has probably the biggest penetration of optical fiber and broadband connections in the world, but the big installation companies and service providers have usually let the old analog systems stay put. Coincidentally I also have a special insight into dorms in my city (population ~700000, with ~40000 "college" students), and the newly built ones are purely digital, but all that are 7-8 years and older (95%) have both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a cable box from the cable provider?  It will give you remote control functionality, DVR functionality, the ability to get more channels, as well as other functions.  The only downside is it might cost you a small monthly fee to rent the box.

Comment: ...the cost and he probably would not be allowed that option being in a dorm.

Comment: exactly. I live in the dorms. It's just like the systems used in hotels. You can't use ur own receiver.